# state store may have migrated to another instance

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

When I try to access state store from stream, I am getting below error.

The state store, count-store, may have migrated to another instance.

When I tried to access ReadOnlyKeyValueStore from store, getting error message as migrated to other server. but am having only one broker is up and running

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.ms.kafka.com.ms.stream;

import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.InvalidStateStoreException;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Consumed;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KTable;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Materialized;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.state.QueryableStoreType;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.state.QueryableStoreTypes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.state.ReadOnlyKeyValueStore;

import com.ms.kafka.com.ms.entity.TrackingEvent;
import com.ms.kafka.com.ms.entity.TrackingEventDeserializer;
import com.ms.kafka.com.ms.entity.TrackingEvnetSerializer;


/**
 * @author vettri
 *
 */
public class EventStreamer {

    /**
     * 
     */
    public EventStreamer() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "trackeventstream_stream");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG,"testappdi");
        props.put("auto.offset.reset","earliest");
        /*
         * props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG,
         * Serdes.String().getClass());
         * props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG,
         * Serdes.String().getClass());
         */

        final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        final KStream<String , TrackingEvent> eventStream = builder.stream("rt_event_command_topic_stream",Consumed.with(Serdes.String(),
                Serdes.serdeFrom(new TrackingEvnetSerializer(), new TrackingEventDeserializer())));
        KTable<String, Long> groupedByUniqueId = eventStream.groupBy((k,v) -> v.getUniqueid()).
                count(Materialized.as("count-store"));
        
        /*
         * KTable<Integer, Integer> table = builder.table( "rt_event_topic_stream",
         * Materialized.as("queryable-store-name"));
         */
        
        //eventStream.filter((k,v) -> "9de3b676-b20f-4b7a-878b-526fd5948a34".equalsIgnoreCase(v.getUniqueid())).foreach((k,v) -> System.out.println(v));
        final KafkaStreams stream = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);
        stream.cleanUp();
        stream.start();
        System.out.println("Strema state : "+stream.state().name());
        String queryableStoreName = groupedByUniqueId.queryableStoreName();
        /*
         * ReadOnlyKeyValueStore keyValStore1 =
         * waitUntilStoreIsQueryable(queryableStoreName, (QueryableStoreTypes)
         * QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore(),stream);
         */ ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<Long , TrackingEvent> keyValStore = stream.store(queryableStoreName, QueryableStoreTypes.<Long,TrackingEvent>keyValueStore());
        
       // System.out.println("results --> "+keyValStore.get((long) 158));
        //streams.close();
    }
    
    public static <T> T waitUntilStoreIsQueryable(final String storeName,
            final QueryableStoreTypes queryableStoreType, final KafkaStreams streams) throws InterruptedException {
        while (true) {
            try {
                return streams.store(storeName, (QueryableStoreType<T>) queryableStoreType);
            } catch (InvalidStateStoreException ignored) {
// store not yet ready for querying
                System.out.println("system is waitng to ready for state store");
                Thread.sleep(100);
                //streams.close();
            }
        }
}

}
```

I need to retrieve the data that i stored in state store,

what am trying to do is, need store it in local and retrieve**strong text**

Comment: How many instance of you Kafka Streams application have you started?

Comment: Could you clean your code and put only code that you use (not lot of commented out)? It is _a little bit_ messy.

Comment: Please find the GITHUB repository URL : https://github.com/nareshmg2304/kafka-stream/blob/master/EventStreamer.java

Comment: am having only one broker with one stream app.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't access your repo. It think it is private one

Comment: Marked them to public, you can access now ...

Answer (score 3):

In your case the local KafkaStreams instance is not yet ready and thus its local state stores cannot be queried yet.

Before querying you should wait for KafkaStreams to be in `RUNNING` status. You need call you `waitUntilStoreIsQueryable(...)`.

Example can be found in Confluent github:

- [waitUntilStoreIsQueryable(...)](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/5.2.1-post/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/IntegrationTestUtils.java#L225) definition
- [usage of waitUntilStoreIsQueryable(...)](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/5.2.1-post/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/ValidateStateWithInteractiveQueriesLambdaIntegrationTest.java#L139)

More details regarding cause can be found here: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/faq.html#handling-invalidstatestoreexception-the-state-store-may-have-migrated-to-another-instance

Comment: I've made small MR, with sample modification to your branch. I didn't have access to your serdes, so I used String as value for message