# Kafka Stream | The state store, comp-store, may have migrated to another instance

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am new to Kafka and stream. I am creating a local store to hold all the updates from a particular topic `components`. I don't what i am doing wrong here. is there any another way to create store from Stream?

Do I need to create a topic `comp-store` in Kafka?

```
public class MyStream {

final static CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);   

    private static final String APP_ID = "MyTestApp";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        final Properties streamsConfiguration = getStreamsConfiguration();
        final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
//        

        final KStream<String, Component> componentStream =  builder.stream("components");

        final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), streamsConfiguration);    

        KeyValueMapper<String, Component, Iterable<KeyValue<String, Component>>> mapper = new KeyValueMapper<String, Component, Iterable<KeyValue<String,Component>>>() {


            @Override
            public Iterable<KeyValue<String, Component>> apply(String list, Component comp) {
                ArrayList<KeyValue<String, Component>> result = new ArrayList<>();
                result.add(KeyValue.pair(comp.getCompId()+":"+comp.getListId(), comp));

                return result;
            }
        };

        KStream<String,Component> componentsStram = componentStream.flatMap(mapper);
        KGroupedStream<String,Component> componentsGroupedStream = componentsStram.groupByKey();

        componentsGroupedStream.reduce(new Reducer<Component>() {

            public Component apply(Component oldVal, Component newVal) {
                return newVal;
            }
        }, Materialized.<String, Component, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("comp-store"));


        streams.start();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true){
                     if(streams.state().isRunning()){
                            latch.countDown();
                        }
                }
            }
        }).start();

        latch.await();

        Thread.sleep(5000);
        ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String,Component> localStore = waitUntilStoreIsQueryable("comp-store", QueryableStoreTypes.<String, Component> keyValueStore(), streams);

        System.out.println(localStore.approximateNumEntries());
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));

    }

    private static Properties getStreamsConfiguration() {

        Properties settings = new Properties();
        settings.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, APP_ID);
        settings.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        settings.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        settings.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, ProtoSerde.class);
        settings.put(StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG, "C:\\temp");
        settings.put("auto.offset.reset","earliest");
        settings.put(StreamsConfig.CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG, 0);
        return settings;
    }

public static <T> T waitUntilStoreIsQueryable(final String storeName, final QueryableStoreType<T> queryableStoreType, final KafkaStreams streams) throws InterruptedException {
    while (true) {
        try {
            return streams.store(storeName, queryableStoreType);
        } catch (InvalidStateStoreException ignored) {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Exception**

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.InvalidStateStoreException: The state store, comp-store, may have migrated to another instance.
at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.QueryableStoreProvider.getStore(QueryableStoreProvider.java:60)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.store(KafkaStreams.java:1038)
at com.mr.streams.MyStream.main(MyStream.java:110)
```

**Update** After `waitUntilStoreIsQueryable` my exception is resolved but still I am not able to query the state store. It seems it is going in infinite loop. However data is there in `componentsStram`. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: check following posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55499553/state-store-may-have-migrated-to-another-instance, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50011543/kafka-streams-persistent-store-error-the-state-store-may-have-migrated-to-anot and official Confluent documentation: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/faq.html#handling-invalidstatestoreexception-the-state-store-may-have-migrated-to-another-instance

Comment: @wardziniak seems its worked!

Comment: looks like store is not at all ready for query landing in infinite loop.

Comment: You call `builder.build()` too early. After you called it, and modification to your program are not reflected in the created `Topology`. In your code snippet, it's basically only a single source node that read from topic "components". You should call `builder.build()` as last step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exception is thrown because Kafka Streams instance is not ready yet.

According to documentation: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/faq.html#interactive-queries there might be two reason of above exception:

- The local KafkaStreams instance is not yet ready and thus its local state stores cannot be queried yet.
- The local KafkaStreams instance is ready, but the particular state store was just migrated to another instance behind the scenes.

The easiest way to deal with it is to wait till state store will be queryable:

```java
public static <T> T waitUntilStoreIsQueryable(final String storeName,
                                              final QueryableStoreType<T> queryableStoreType,
                                              final KafkaStreams streams) throws InterruptedException {
  while (true) {
    try {
      return streams.store(storeName, queryableStoreType);
    } catch (InvalidStateStoreException ignored) {
      // store not yet ready for querying
      Thread.sleep(100);
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**:

You have to move createion of KafkaStream after defining whole topology:
line: `final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), streamsConfiguration);` should go after: `componentsGroupedStream.reduce(...)`

Comment: My Exception is resolved but dont know why my state store is not ready for query. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: @amicngh, I've updated my answer. you create KafkaStreams to early. You have to move it after defining whole topology